# thymeleaf HTML error

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I'm trying to create a webpage using Thymeleaf.Everything is set up right I manage to get into the homepage and then trying to use a link to another page but I get the following error:

"Exception parsing document: template="lor1", line 70 - column 68"
 **and** "lineNumber: 70; columnNumber: 68; Element type "a" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

However the homepage is using  and is working perfectly.

Here's the code:

```
<title>League Of Ronnie</title>
 <link href="../../../resources/css/style.css"
      th:href="@{/resources/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
<div id="background">
    <div id="header">
        <div>
            <div>
                <a th:href="@{/}" class="logo"><img th:src="@{/resources/images/logo.png}" alt="" /></a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html" id="menu1">home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="media.html" id="menu2">the world</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="games.html" id="menu3">the game</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="about.html" id="menu4">about</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="selected">
                        <a href="blog.html" id="menu5">the ronnie</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="blog">
                    <div class="content">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div class="header">
                                    <b id="a1">Warrior</b><span><a href="#" id="a2">STRENGTH</a><a href="#" id="a3">SWORD</a><a href="#" id="a4">PLATE</a></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="article">
                                    <a href="#" class="figure"><img id="im1" src="images/img1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                                    <p>
                                        You can replace all this text with your own text. You can remove any link to our website from this website template, you're free to use this website template without linking back to us. If you're having problems editing this website template, then don't hesitate to ask for help on the <a href="http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com/forums/">Forum</a>.<br/>
                                        <a href="blog.html" class="more">read more</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sidebar">
                        <div>
                            <span><a href="'javascript:change1();'" class="selected" id="l1">Classes</a></span> <span><a href="'javascript:change2();'" id="l2">Servants</a></span>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="'javascript:Warrior();'" id="b1">Warrior</a>
                                <span><a href="2.html
                                " id="b2">STRENGTH</a><a href="#" id="b3">SWORD</a><a href="#" id="b4">PLATE</a></span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="'javascript:Paladin();'" id="b5">Paladin</a>
                                <span><a href="2.html" id="b6">JUSTICE</a><a href="2.html"id="b7">HAMMER</a><a href="2.html" id="b8">PLATE</a></span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="'javascript:Assassin();'" id="b9">Assassin</a>
                                <span><a href="2.html"id="b10">AGILITY</a><a href="#" id="b11">DAGGER</a><a href="#" id="b12">LEATHER</a></span>    
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="'javascript:Ranger();'" id="b13">Ranger</a>
                                <span><a href="2.html" id="b14">FOCUS</a><a href="#" id="b15">BOW</a><a href="#" id="b16">LEATHER</a></span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="'javascript:Mage();'" id="b17">Mage</a>
                                <span><a href="#" id="b18">SPELLPOWER</a><a href="#" id="b19">STAFF</a><a href="#" id="b20">CLOTH</a></span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="'javascript:Priest();'" id="b21">Priest</a>
                                <span><a href="#" id="b22">SPIRIT</a><a href="#" id="b23">RELIC</a><a href="#" id="b24">CLOTH</a></span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="'javascript:Warlock();'" id="b25">Warlock</a>
                                <span><a href="#" id="b26">CURSE</a><a href="#" id="b27">SCEPTER</a><a href="#" id="b28">CLOTH</a></span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="'javascript:Warlord();'" id="b29">Warlord</a>
                                <span><a href="#" id="b30">FURY</a><a href="#" id="b31">AXE</a><a href="#" id="b32">PLATE</a></span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li id="facebook">
                    <a href="http://freewebsitetemplates.com/go/facebook/">facebook</a>
                </li>
                <li id="twitter">
                    <a href="http://freewebsitetemplates.com/go/twitter/">twitter</a>
                </li>
                <li id="googleplus">
                    <a href="http://freewebsitetemplates.com/go/googleplus/">googleplus</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <p>
                @ copyright 2012. all rights reserved.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/resources/lor.js}"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is at line 70 of the template `lor1`?

Comment: <span><a href="2.html" id="b6">JUSTICE</a><a href="2.html"id="b7">HAMMER</a><a href="2.html" id="b8">PLATE</a></span>.normally its a href="#" but i changed it for a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error comes from a missing space between the href attribute (2.html) and the id attribute (b7).
It should be :

```
<span><a href="2.html" id="b6">JUSTICE</a><a href="2.html" id="b7">HAMMER</a><a href="2.html" id="b8">PLATE</a></span>
```

Comment: thx a lot i guess i need some practice on syntax error.another thing now the part <div ="sidebar"> is not ccs'ed,maybe you know why?

Comment: You mean <div class="sidebar"> ? Well, first thing I'd check is if the CSS is properly imported when loading the page. You can check that with your browser dev tools or by coding a dummy class like : dummy { color: red; } and styling some text with it. Once you're absolutely sure your CSS stylesheet(s) is (are) loaded, it must be something within its code then... If that's the case and you can't figure out the problem, I guess you'll have to create a new question and post your CSS code. Cheers

Comment: The rest of the CSS is working perfectly.Also I've compared it to the original CSS file(I downloaded both the HTML and CSS) and at that point they are exactly the same.I got it working in a previous try I mindlessly erased so I guess it's an error in the HTML page.